# Is there any program for ubuntu which handles pptx file properly?

Tags: libreoffice, openoffice.org, microsoft-office, microsoft-powerpoint

When I open up a pptx file with LibreOffice/OpenOffice some of the contents,text,style,colors get messed up. I searched in the web but couldn't find any proper solution for this. Can anyone help me in this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you require something that you can run locally, I'd recommend [WPS Office](http://wps-community.org/downloads).  It seems to handle complex layouts reasonably well.

Answer (score 1):

Use [MS Office Online](https://products.office.com/en-us/office-online/documents-spreadsheets-presentations-office-online).  It's free.